# using Qt's QProcess as popen (with ffmpeg rawvideo)

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, popen, qprocess

I inserted some code in a video application to export using ffmpeg
with stdin (rawideo rgba format), to quickly test that it worked I
used `popen()`, the tests went well and since the application is
written using Qt I thought of modify the patch using `QProcess` and
`->write()`.

The application shows no errors and works properly but the generated
video files are not playable neither with vlc nor with mplayer while
those generated with `popen()` work perfectly with both.  I have the
feeling that `->close()` or `->terminate()` does not properly close
ffmpeg and consequently the file, but I don't know how to verify it
nor I found alternative ways to end the executed command, beside
`->waitForBytesWritten()` should wait for the data to be written,
suggestions? Am I doing something wrong?

(Obviously I can't prepare a testable example it would take me more
time than the patch took)

Below is the code I entered, in the case `#else` the Qt code

Initialization

```
#if defined(EXPORT_POPEN) && EXPORT_POPEN == 1
      pipe_frame.file = popen("/tmp/ffmpeg-rawpipe.sh", "w");
      if (pipe_frame.file == NULL) {
        return false;
      }
#else
      pipe_frame.qproc = new QProcess;
      pipe_frame.qproc->start("/tmp/ffmpeg-rawpipe.sh", QIODevice::WriteOnly);
      if(!pipe_frame.qproc->waitForStarted()) {
        return false;
      }
#endif
```

Writing a frame

```
#if defined(EXPORT_POPEN) && EXPORT_POPEN == 1
          fwrite(pipe_frame.data, pipe_frame.width*4*pipe_frame.height , 1, pipe_frame.file);
#else
          qint64 towrite = pipe_frame.width*4*pipe_frame.height,
            written = 0, partial;
          while(written < towrite) {
            partial = pipe_frame.qproc->write(&pipe_frame.data[written], towrite-written);
            pipe_frame.qproc->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
            written += partial;
          }
#endif
```

Termination

```
#if defined(EXPORT_POPEN) && EXPORT_POPEN == 1
      pclose(pipe_frame.file);
#else
      pipe_frame.qproc->terminate();
      //pipe_frame.qproc->close();
#endif
```

**edit**

ffmpeg-rawpipe.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ffmpeg-cuda -y -f rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt rgba -r 25 -i - -an -c:v h264_nvenc \
        -cq:v 19 \
        -profile:v high /tmp/test.mp4
```

I made some changes, I added the unbuffered flag to the open

```
pipe_frame.qproc->start("/tmp/ffmpeg-rawpipe.sh", QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Unbuffered);
```

And therefore simplified the write

```
qint64 towrite = pipe_frame.width*4*pipe_frame.height;
pipe_frame.qproc->write(pipe_frame.data, towrite);
pipe_frame.qproc->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
```

I added a closeWriteChannel before closing the application (hoping that stopping the stdin ffmpeg pipe ends properly, just in case, I'm not sure it doesn't)

```
pipe_frame.qproc->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
pipe_frame.qproc->closeWriteChannel();
//pipe_frame.qproc->terminate();
pipe_frame.qproc->close();
```

But nothing changes, the mp4 file is created and contains data but from the mplayer log I see that it is misinterpreted, the video format is not recognized and it looks for an audio that is not there.

Comment: share the .sh ...

Comment: @eyllanesc Sure, I add it to the answer but it's not relevant, the same .sh is used for popen and QProcess.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, adding `waitForFinished()` after `closeWriteChannel()`, closes stdin and wait for ffmpeg to terminate on its own.

```
pipe_frame.qproc->waitForBytesWritten(-1); // perhaps not necessary
pipe_frame.qproc->closeWriteChannel();
pipe_frame.qproc->waitForFinished();
pipe_frame.qproc->close();
```

**edit**

Note, even if initialized with the unbuffered flag, QProcess and QIODevice seem to buffer quite a lot, it seems as if `waitForBytesWritten ()` is not working, and if you are feeding HD video you will go out of memory very quickly.